# Explanation of RAD Studio source code markers/visualizations

Tags: delphi, ide, pascal, continue, code-editor

I was interested to know if the code markers shown at the end of some lines (see screenshot) are explained or documented anywhere (for RAD Studio 10.4).
I notice that the first 3 (for `Halt`, `Continue` and `Break`) will disappear when these items are prefixed with the unit name `System.`.

As for `raise`, it's not clear to me what the little red up arrow signifies or how it should be addressed. Code compiles fine without errors, warnings or hints.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if False then Halt(99);

  for I := 0 to 2 do
  begin
    if I = 0 then Continue;
    if I = 1 then Break;
  end;

  try
    Transaction.StartTransaction;
    //update database
    Transaction.Commit;
  except
    Transaction.Rollback;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Code in editor with markers]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those arrows belong to [Flow Control Highlighting](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Code_Editor#Flow_Control_Highlighting). They are visual cues that illustrate jumps (interruptions) in the regular, linear, code flow.

For instance, `Break` arrow points down and it visually shows that code execution will jump out of the current loop down to the first next code line outside the loop.

`raise` arrow symbolizes jumping out of the current code (bubbling up) to the next exception handler.

The fact some of them disappear when they are prefixed with `System` namespace is merely a bug in the parser responsible for painting the highlighting. Actual behavior of the code will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had not found the info regarding Flow Control Highlighting.